# bitbucket -ошибка при комите: Push rejected: Push to origin/master was rejected

Tags: github, bitbucket

Ребята помогите разобраться, с вопросом:  В github делаю комиты и поучаю.

Но сегодня решил попробовать на bitbucket, через phpstorm. Делал как обычно, создал репозиторий, скопировал ссылку в phpstorm... и.тд.  Но когда   делаю push - получаю ошибку:

```
Push rejected: Push to origin/master was rejected
```

PS. Если можно дайте пару советов какой репозиторий выбрать.

А также как настроить  в редакторе 2 независимых репозитория для одного проекта, чтобы мог выбрать куда сливать а куда нет. Например один приватный а второй для группы. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался сам:

1)  На Bitbucket нужно создать чистый репозиторий без файла redme

```
Create a new repository: include a redme = no
Version control = GIT
```

закачиваем 2 плагина для шторма:

2)  `Bitbucket Linky`  --обеспечивает удобную навигацию по Atlassian Bitbucket. Он автоматически определяет репозитории, размещенные на Bitbucket Cloud или Bitbucket Server.
В большинстве случаев настройка не требуется. Однако если Linky не может автоматически определить репозиторий, можно вручную указать его в параметрах среды IDE.
Linky удобен в проекте:
он копирует или открывает ссылку на выбранный файл или фиксирует в Bitbucket. Предоставляет простой способ создания ссылки на определенное место в коде или перехода к репозиторию из среды IDE.

3)  `Bitbucket -GetLink` создаёт ярлыки для открытия файла или фиксации в Stash, GitHub,
BitBucket, GitLab или GitBlit с помощью браузера по умолчанию или скопировать ссылку в буфер обмена.

```
После установки выбираем: Settings/Other settings / Get Link 
В настройках параметров можем выбрать: 
Hosts: Bitbucket, GitHub, stash, GitLab, GitBlit, Custom
Default Branch: master
Remote name: origin
```